# pca9685 alternative

Tags: electrical-engineering, pwm

As chip shortage continues, it is harder to get the above mentioned IC.(used to drive various LEDs )
I struggle to find an alternative based on the points mentioned below, maybe someone encountered some similar IC ?

Main points would be:

I2C -fast mode plus is not a must. 400 kHz is good enough
16 channels or more
12-bit resolution or more
The bigger the I2C address range the better

Comment: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Off topic but why do your points exclude cost, qty, package type? When low stock qty exists